# eXistdb REST api with _xsl and _query parameter not returning text/html

Tags: rest, xslt, exist-db, media-type

I have just started learning the eXist database and am intrigued by the REST api built into it.

The application that I am using requires querying a file and then applying an xslt stylesheet to the result, but the REST api is not returning the correct media type (**text/html**).  I am using the `_xsl` and `_query` parameters (along with `_wrap=no` to avoid eXist wrapping results when using `_query`).

According to *eXist* by Erik Siegel and Adam Retter (O'Reilly, 2014), when using the `_xsl` parameter,

> Applying an XSLT stylesheet in this manner always changes the
>   response's Internet media type to **text/html**.

(page 98, bold added by me), however, I am getting back **application/xml** (confirmed using the LiveHTTPHeaders plugin in Firefox).

Consider the following documents in the database

### /db/apps/testing/example.xml

```
<items>
    <item>This is item 1</item>
    <item>This is item 2</item>
</items>
```

### /db/apps/testing/example.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head><title>Testing</title></head>
                <body>                
                    <ul>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
                    </ul>
                </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="items">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then this url (applying the stylesheet to the whole document)

```
http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/testing/example.xml?_xsl=/db/apps/testing/example.xsl
```

returns an html page (which is correctly rendered as the media type is **text/html**), but this url (first selecting only one item element and then applying the stylesheet)

```
http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/testing/example.xml?_query=/items/item[1]&wrap=no&_xsl=/db/apps/testing/example.xsl
```

returns an xml file (**application/xml**)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>This is item 1</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

The result here is correct, but it is served with the wrong media-type.

It seems that adding the `_query` parameter in order to first select only part of the document causes the media-type to be **application/xml** instead of **text/html**, and the behavior described by Siegel and Retter is only true if the `_xsl` parameter occurs by itself.

Is there a way to cause the second url which first filters the file to return **text/html** as well?  Or is this behavior impossible with the REST api?

(Note: I know that I can pass parameters to an XQuery script and have that script both filter and transform the data, but I am interested in using the REST api to do the work here if possible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the code of eXist and do not see any way to get the results you want by using a `GET` request on the REST interface. However, you can do a `POST`. Here is an illustration of how it can be done using `wget`. Note that whereas you put your files under `/db/apps/testing/`, when I uploaded your files to my eXist instance for testing I put them under `/db/testing/` (no `apps`). Adjust the paths as needed in what follows.

Create a file named `post.xml` with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist"
       wrap="no">
  <text>/items/item[1]</text>
  <properties>
    <property name="stylesheet" value="/db/testing/example.xsl"/>
    <property name="media-type" value="text/html"/>
  </properties>
</query>
```

Then issue this command:

```
wget -S --post-file=post.xml --header='Content-Type: application/xml'
     http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/testing/example.xml
```

Or the equivalent. You need to have the content of `post.xml` as the content of the `POST` request, and the `Content-Type` header must be `application/xml`. The `-S` option dumps the response headers to the screen. So when I run the above, I get this on the console:

```
--2016-06-15 12:12:10--  http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/testing/example.xml
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Wed, 15 Jun 2016 16:12:10 GMT
  Set-Cookie: [...]
  Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
  Last-Modified: Tue, 14 Jun 2016 12:21:56 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Server: Jetty(8.1.9.v20130131)
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘example.xml’

example.xml                                              [ <=>                                                                                                                  ]     154  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2016-06-15 12:12:10 (6.67 MB/s) - ‘example.xml’ saved [154]
```

Note how the response's `Content-Type` is `text/html`. `wget` saves the results in a local file named `example.xml` which contains the expected data:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>This is item 1</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The goal was so that I can serve a listing page like: `<ul><li><a href="link_to_item_1">item1</a></li> <!-- other items --> </ul>` and then provide links like I listed in my question.  If I have to use a post mode, I can't provide clickable links.  Right now I am forwarding the url to a xquery script (with controller.xqy) which runs the query and then the transformation, but I had hoped to let the REST api do the heavy lifting beings it already almost does everything I need.  However, if it can't be done, then I'll have to stick to this way (which is probably more secure anyways).

Comment: +1 as this answer is helpful.  I'm going to let the question remain open for a little while to see if anybody does know a way to do it the way I wanted, otherwise, I'll accept this one.

Comment: I won't feel offended if you want to leave my answer unaccepted. :) There may be a better way to do it. I'm pretty sure though that doing what you want to do with eXist 2.2 and a `GET` of the type you show in the question is impossible. When I looked at the code, I saw that the code path taken when there is no `_query` forces the MIME type to `text/html` if no explicit MIME type has been requested but a stylesheet was specified. When you do specify `_query`, the code path taken is very different and does not have anything equivalent to set the MIME type.